# Kibana display field value on time

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-5

In ElasticSearch I have these following documents (values like index and type was removed) :

```
@timestamp:March 29th 2017, 22:03:29.152 totalQuantity:154 
@timestamp:March 29th 2017, 22:06:30.242 totalQuantity:153 
@timestamp:March 29th 2017, 22:06:32.735 totalQuantity:152
```

Now I want to display the totalQuantity's value evolution during time (in line chart or other graph, maybe timelion) with 3 node

- Y: 154 X: 22-03-29
- Y: 153 X: 22:06:30
- Y: 152 X: 22:06:32

But I can't find how to deal with it, as I only have count, sum, median, etc on these graph but not term.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to create a line/bar chart and set x-axis as date histogram where @timestamp is the property, and put sum or average of totalQuantity on y-axis. You will want to set your time interval in seconds so you will see the difference 2 seconds later. No need for TimeLion as you are not calculating anything.

Comment: So sum is applyed on all document in these 2 seconds? So if I understand it well, In order to don't have wrong value cause by sum,my data have to be separated from more than 2 sec? Is it right

Comment: Ok I saw that kibana auto scale my interval to 10 sec that's why I have wrong value and only 2 node with 10 document